# Log in page does not work properly

Tags: livecode

I create a login page with user name and password. In password field I am changed to character to "*" while click the button for login I can't login

--- the following code is for password field
global var

```
put "shalu@123" into var
on keydown var
   set  the hiddentext of me to the hiddentext of me & var
   put "*" after me
end keydown
```

---main coding

```
global Username, var

on openCard
put "shalu" into sUsername
put "shalu@123" into var
end openCard

on loginCheck
if field "FF1" is sUsername and field "FF2" is var then
answer "Login Successful"
--go to card "accessed"
else
answer "Details Incorrect. Please try again!"
end if
end loginCheck
```

is it any alternative method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned what the exact problem is -- are you getting an error somewhere?  One issue might be mismatched variables: you have global **Username** and script variable **sUserName**.

Also, is this all your code?  If yes, you're not calling the loginCheck handler anywhere, so no comparison is taking place.  Your button should be calling loginCheck.

If this is for desktop, you can also use a combination of enterInField and returnInField in the card script to trigger loginCheck when pressing those keys in either field (Note: doing this will catch enter/return messages in ALL fields, so you need to code appropriately if you have additional fields on the card).

But the button should be the main control to initiate loginCheck.

Comment: Thank you @Scott Rossi i have place a button and name it as login while clicking that button it shows "Details Incorrect. Please try again!" even i have enter the correct password

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your `global Username, var` is correct. Shouldn't that maybe be `global sUsername, var`?

Also, I usually add some `put sUsername` or `answer sUsername` statements into my code so I can in the message box see what value a certain variable has at some point. Later I comment them out so they are not exectued in a delivery version